# UITextView doesn't parse escape characters

Tags: iphone, xcode

So I have an array that is filled in by parsing an XML file. In the file, there are lines that contain '\n' for a next-line character.

When I try to display said lines

```
self.myTextView.text = _myString;
```

it displays in the simulator as

```
\nLorem \nipsum \ndolor \nsit \namet ....
```

(It prints the same way through console - However, if I manually set

```
self.myTextView.text = @"\nLorem \nipsum \ndolor \nsit \namet";
```

it will display as

```
Lorem
ipsum
dolor
sit
amet
```

Does anyone know how to work around this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input string literally contains the characters `\n` which have no special meaning outside of a C-compiler (or Java, or C++ or Objective-C, etc.).

If you want the `\n` characters converted to newlines then you need to do this yourself, perhaps using:

```
self.myTextView.text = [_myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n"
                                                            withString:@"\n"];
```

Comment: @mrcharlie Note that if the input strings contains any other escape sequences (like `\t` for "tab") then you'll need to repeatedly perform this substitution...

Comment: @mrcharlie You had confused the behaviour of *string literals* with the behaviour of *string data*.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the XML encoding of the string inserts escaping characters before the newlines and you have to remove them first.